# WooCommerce Custom Template Adding Only Last Product in the row to the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show specific products in a table list view with their own custom field for specific user; couldn't achieve this with any plugins so started to code my own. Only this user/wholesaler will view this page.

But before going that far in the code I got stuck on "ADD TO CART" Button submission. Whichever product I try to add only the last product in the row gets submitted.
Here's the code:

```
    <h1> PRODUCT TABLE LIST </h1>
            <table>

            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Note Box</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Choose Quantiy</th>
                <th>Product Total Quantity</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product', 
        'posts_per_page' => 15, 
        'product_cat' => '', 
        'post__in' => array( 481, 478, 934 ),
        'orderby' => 'title' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>



                <tr class="product-<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>">    

                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">



<td>
                        <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>

</td>

<td>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" placeholder="Choose up to 16 letters or Numbers" />
</td>

<td>
<span class="price">
<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
</span>                    
</td>

</a>

    <td>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>SC1</th>
            <td><input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>KW1</th>
        <td><input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</td>

<td><input name="quantity" data-min="1" data-max="0" value="1" size="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" maxlength="12" type="number"></td>

<td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />


<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
</td>

</tr>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


            </tbody>
            </table>
```

I have tried to use **woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product)** but it doesn't submit the quantity value.

Comment: The problem is fixed by adding `<?php woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart() ?>` but now both quantity and Add to cart button are inside same table cell `<td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use form `<form>` after your table row `<tr>`

For single products use:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

For variable products use:

```
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you, I already solved it. But forgot to update here.
I didn't declare any Form Action anywhere in my code; lol.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to create different tempalte for woo commerce cart. woocommerce give you to chnage this its own templates.

copy the files under templates folder from woocommerce plugin and paste these files to you theme folder under the "woocommerce" folder. (you have to create woocommerce folder in your theme). now you can modify woocommerce templates.

Comment: I have already used template override for quest user (unregistered).

Comment: I have already used template override for guest user (unregistered user).
But for a registered user I want to show some specific products from all the categories into table format. Those products are already available for guest users in normal layout.

These products will have two specific custom field only for the specific registered user.

I don't want to create new products as I will maintain stock from same products.